# Scrolling to a certain custom cell when loading the table

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm bulding a celander application and i want the calender to get scrolled to the current month when started. i used custom cell for each month. the code that i found to make this happen from this website is this:

```
    [self.bahraincld reloadData];

    NSIndexPath *scrollto = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1];

    [self.bahraincld scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollto
                           atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

I'm using it in the view did load. it's giving me a signal SIGABRT.

- is this code correct? where should i use it if i want it to work whenever the user starts the calendar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better put this code into `viewDidAppear`, because your `tableView` haven't loaded the data yet, so the cells are not created. In your case `SIGABRT`, is because row number 2 is beyond bounds.

Comment: Yes it did see my answer for what i did specifically. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did, hop it helps someone.

```
//in the view will appear reload your table.
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
[self.yourtable reloadData];
 }

//in the view did appear, value = defining which costume cell to move to.
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
int value = 5;
NSIndexPath *scrollto = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:value inSection:0];
[self.yourtable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollto
                       atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
 }
```